# I brought my pen, (my) keys, (my) bag etc

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

Do I need to repeat a personal pronoun every time I use some noun with it?

*I brought **my** pen and pencil*

or

*I brought **my** pen and **my** pencil*

What if we have more nouns?

*I took **my** glasses, **my** phone, **my** picture, **my** knife and **my** wallet.*

or

*I took **my** glasses, phone, picture, knife and wallet.*

or

*I took **my** glasses, phone, picture, knife and **my** wallet.*

?

Comment: You don't have to repeat it.

Comment: But what if I live near some building which ia being built. I am a thief. I am saying "I brought my pen and bricks". The questions is whether the bricks are mine, too, or I brought my pen but the bricks I brought were of the builders', not mine? How to distinguish it?

Comment: The 'my' is presumed to cover all things listed after it.

Comment: Then how should I say the sentence with the bricks that are not mine?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko You could say, "my pen and some bricks".

Comment: You can also move the possession to the end: "I brought bricks and my pen."

Comment: I bought my chicken, turkey, sheep and cow, and a donkey that was not mine.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Ingenious!

Comment: @MicahWindsor But won't it sound like "My pen and some of my bricks"? In this case the bricks are again mine.

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko If it's really so important that they are stolen, and you can't just say "I stole the bricks", just say "I brought my pen and some stolen bricks". What's most important is that you brought them, not that you have stolen them.

Comment: @MicahWindsor 1) But what if I found them? I don't know whether somebody owned them. If I say "stolen" it can be misleading information. 2) "and some stolen bricks" - stolen by whom? Maybe just not to get insane because of all of these variants I'm allowed to say "my" every time - "I brought my pen and my bricks"? I mustn't say thus or I am allowed to?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko You already said they belonged to the builders... therefore you stole them. If you wanted to be really clear that you stole them, just say "some bricks I stole".

Comment: @MicahWindsor Oh, yeah, sorry, I got tangled. Just the thing is if I add "I stole" it will give the information I stole them, if I add "found" it will mean I found them but what if I got them as a gift but don't want to mention this fact? Like, the pen is mine but the bricks aren't but how I got them is something I want to omit. In this case I am probably obliged to say "that are not mine". Turns out, this phrase is inevitable... :(

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to repeat "my".

Listeners will generally understand "my" to determine all of the items in the list

> I brought my pen, book and bag.

If the ownership is different, and important, you can mention it

> I brought my pen, book, and Katie's notepad that she'd lent me.

It is quite common to repeat "my" and not strange:

> I brought my pen, my book, and Katie's notepad that she'd lent me.

You've brought up a fairly weird example in the comments:

> I brought my pen and bricks.

Wait, what? This is a very unlikely situation, but *deja-vu* Don't get yourself tied in knots: nobody ever says this.  If they did we would probably understand because it would be one of those special occasions when people gather and are expected to bring a brick or two.  I've never been to that kind of party, but if you have, that's cool.

Comment: Parties where people bring bricks are often referred to as “riots”.